# create custom module, get existing module configuration

Tags: module, custom, configuration, ups

I would like to create a custom module, I want to get used to the `vendor/magento/module-ups/` module, and use the same config in my custom module, such as userID, password, access key.

how can I include it in my custom module?

I want to get used to the below function in my custom module.

Please advise.

```
    protected function setXMLAccessRequest()
    {
        $userId = $this->getConfigData('username');
        $userIdPass = $this->getConfigData('password');
        $accessKey = $this->getConfigData('access_license_number');

        $this->_xmlAccessRequest = <<<XMLAuth
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<AccessRequest xml:lang="en-US">
  <AccessLicenseNumber>$accessKey</AccessLicenseNumber>
  <UserId>$userId</UserId>
  <Password>$userIdPass</Password>
</AccessRequest>
XMLAuth;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have your *class extend* `Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrierOnline` which should allow you to call the *public* `getConfigData()` *function*. That function is defined in `Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier`, however *AbstractCarrierOnline extends* that on, so for the sake of having that function available either of those two *abstract classes* should to the trick.

A more general answer - often, but not exclusively, seen in `Magento\SomeModule\Helper\Data` classes - is to create a helper class for your module as well, extend `Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper` and do something similar to

```
$storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
$sys_conf_val = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('sys/conf/valpath', $storeScope));
```